# Does the Struts tags prevents XSS

Tags: struts, xss

I am using Struts 1.1 version. Fortify scan tools reports the possibility of XSS attacks in Form parameters. Do the Struts tags prevents the xss attack by default

Answer (score 1):

Struts 1.X version came to EOL. If you are in initial stage it's time to switch Struts2. Yes Struts 1.1 has some chance of XSS Vulnerability. Check [this site](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsXssVulnerability) for more information. To prevent XSS `(Cross-site scripting)` atleast you need [upgrade](http://struts.apache.org/struts-doc-1.2.8/userGuide/release-notes.html) to Struts 1.2.8. You can configure your Servlet Container to use a Custom Error Page for 404 / Not Found errors. Like this,

```
<struts-config>
   <action-mappings>
       <action path="/unknown" forward="/CustomNotFoundError.jsp" 
                                                          unknown="true" />
   </action-mappings>
 </struts-config>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm working on a web app with Struts 1.3.10 and i can do XSS attack. Any good example how i can protect myself?